# "Hello world" in x64 assembly for Windows - Shadow space / Stack alignment

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, amd64

I`m currently trying to delve into x64 assembly under windows using NASM, and created a minimalistic "Hello World" application.

It is mainly meant as an educational resource for me and possibly others, hence the heavy documentation style.

A full repo with build instructions and code is located at [hello_kernel32](https://github.com/RaphMad/hello_kernel32), this is the relevant source file:

```
;; Resources:
;; https://sonictk.github.io/asm_tutorial/
;; https://gist.github.com/mcandre/b3664ffbeb4f5764b36a397fafb04f1c
;; https://retroscience.net/x64-assembly.html


;; Make clear this file contains 64bit assembly
bits 64

;; Use rip-relative addressing
default rel

;; Export entry symbol (this is specified in the call to link.exe)
global _start

;; Import external symbols
;; (all of them exist in kernel32.lib, which gets passed to link.exe in addition to the programs object file hello.obj)
;;
;; Why import symbols/functions from kernel32.lib?
;;
;; In windows, the "low level API stack" is: Kernel < Syscalls < ntdll.dll < kernel32.dll (and others like user32.dll)
;;
;; * The kernel itself cannot be accessed by user programs for obvious reasons (CPU ring protection modes)
;; * Syscalls could be performed, but are undocumented and evidently unstable between different versions of windows
;; * ntdll.dll is only partially documented and not intended for external use
;; * kernel32.dll (and friends) are the "official" low-level entry points to the windows API
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess


;; This section contains read-only data
section .rodata

;; Store the output string followed by CRLF as a sequence of bytes, at address 'msg'
msg db "Hello World!", 0x0d, 0x0a

;; The length will be needed by the output function, and can be statically calculated at assembly time by using 'equ'
;; It is actually a nifty trick that calculates the offset between the current address '$', and the address of 'msg'
;; See https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4
msg_len equ $ - msg


;; This section contains the code
section .text

_start:
    ;; For being able to print text, we first need to acquire a HANDLE to STDOUT
    ;; This HANDLE is a required parameter for the call to WriteFile

    ;; HANDLE = GetStdHandle(-11)
    ;;
    ;; See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle
    ;;
    ;; Parameter 1 (rcx): requests the type of HANDLE, -11 is the constant for STDOUT
    ;; Return value (rax): HANDLE (an address with some type of meaning) is stored in rax, as per calling conventions
    mov rcx, -11
    sub rsp, 40 ;; Allocate 32 bytes of shadow space and 8 bytes to keep the stack 16-byte aligned
    call GetStdHandle
    add rsp, 40 ;; Undo shadow space + alignment padding

    ;; code = WriteFile(HANDLE, msg, msg_len, NULL, NULL)
    ;;
    ;; See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile
    ;;
    ;; Parameter 1 (rcx): HANDLE to write to
    ;; Parameter 2 (rdx): Address of message to print
    ;; Parameter 3 (r8): Length of message
    ;; Parameter 4 (r9): Write amount of written bytes to this address, null pointer
    ;;                   (Required according to docs when parameter 5 is null, but passing null seems to work just fine)
    ;; Parameter 5 (on stack): Unused optional parameter, null pointer
    ;; Return value (rax): Nonzero on success
    mov rcx, rax
    mov rdx, msg
    mov r8, msg_len
    mov r9, 0
    push qword 0
    sub rsp, 32 ;; The previous push aligned us to 16 bytes, only allocate shadow space
    call WriteFile
    add rsp, 40 ;; Undo shadow space + push

    ;; ExitProcess(code)
    ;;
    ;; See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess
    ;;
    ;; Parameter 1 (rcx): Exit code
    mov rcx, rax
    sub rsp, 40 ;; Shadow space + 8 byte alignment
    call ExitProcess
    ;; add rsp, 40 ;; Not necessary because the previous function call will end the program anyway
```

My main question is about:

- **Shadow space + stack alignment**

Most resources I found seem to completely neglect this when doing simple "hello world" programs.
My program also seems to run just fine when removing all the `sub rsp`/`add rsp` statements.

So I'm wondering what the implications of not following those conventions really means for code correctness.

My current understanding is that `GetStdHandle`/`WriteFile`/`ExitProcess` are simply not using shadow space and also do not perform any operation that requires an aligned stack in their *current implementation as present on my machine*.

However, any update to `kernel32.dll` is free to change those implementations in a way that relies on shadow space being present and/or an aligned stack.

Therefore code neglecting shadow space/stack alignment for external calls is *incorrect* in the general sense of incorrectly interfacing with an external API, even though many APIs may be built in a way they can tolerate that slightly incorrect access (but this tolerance is an implementation detail that may change at any time).

-> **Is this definition/understanding correct? / Anything to add/clarify?**

- **General question**

Are there any other apparent mistakes / misunderstandings in the code or comments?

Comment: About your specific questions, I would search Stack Overflow for answers, if I didn't find any answers I would ask a question. Code review is really only about improving code through general reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Shadow space + stack alignment
>
> Most resources I found seem to completely neglect this when doing
> simple "hello world" programs.

Is this true? Keep in mind that the most common way to take it into account is to do something like the following:

- in the prologue, allocate however much space this function ever needs (including the parameter and shadow space of any callee), plus either 8 to compensate for the `call` to that function or using `push rbp` to both save `rbp` *and* restore alignment.
- in the body of the function, don't change `rsp` (eg don't `push qword 0` but `mov qword [rsp + something], 0`).

I looked at a few tutorials and guides, and they used that technique. [That technique is semi-required on win64 anyway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/prolog-and-epilog?view=msvc-170), at least if you want SEH  unwinding, since the stack unwinding data is quite restrictive in what it can express. Code that employs that technique *looks like* it's neglecting alignment and shadow space, but they are taken into account in the amount of stack space allocated by the prologue.

Anyway I recommend that you employ that technique also, even if you aren't emitting unwinding information yet, you may as well get used to it.